# Using EPPlus Excel. Got an error after file saving

Tags: .net, file, filestream, epplus

there is an Excel file on the server with one line in it. I'm trying to do next:

```
try
            {
                using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/DiscountLog" + ".xlsx"), FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
                {
                    using (ExcelPackage pp = new ExcelPackage(fs))
                    {
                        ExcelWorksheet wss = pp.Workbook.Worksheets[1];
                        int CurrentRow = wss.Dimension.Rows + 1;
                        wss.Cells[CurrentRow, 1].Value = model.FirstName;
                        wss.Cells[CurrentRow, 2].Value = model.LastName;
                        wss.Cells[CurrentRow, 3].Value = model.DiscountCard;
                        wss.Cells[CurrentRow, 4].Value = model.PhoneNumber;
                        wss.Cells[CurrentRow, 5].Value = model.Email;
                        wss.Cells[CurrentRow, 6].Value = DateTime.Now.ToString();
                        pp.SaveAs(fs);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

            }
```

There is no error in the process, however when I try to open the file, I ask it to restore it.

Comment: This might be obvious to you, but how are you sure there isn't an error when you are swallowing all exceptions, and not doing anything with the error information?

Comment: I've removed try catch-block.
Th main reason is that this package didnt work in streams with existing files. Answer will be below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct code is:

```
var fileinfo = new FileInfo(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/DiscountLog" + ".xlsx"));
            if (fileinfo.Exists)
            {
                using (ExcelPackage pp = new ExcelPackage(fileinfo))
                {
                    ExcelWorksheet wss = pp.Workbook.Worksheets[1];
                    int CurrentRow = wss.Dimension.Rows + 1;
                    wss.Cells[CurrentRow, 1].Value = model.FirstName;
                    wss.Cells[CurrentRow, 2].Value = model.LastName;
                    wss.Cells[CurrentRow, 3].Value = model.DiscountCard;
                    wss.Cells[CurrentRow, 4].Value = model.PhoneNumber;
                    wss.Cells[CurrentRow, 5].Value = model.Email;
                    wss.Cells[CurrentRow, 6].Value = DateTime.Now.ToString();
                    pp.Save();
                }
            }
            else
            {
            }
```